# setGradientCenter (gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter) is not working in GradientDrawable

Tags: android, gradient, drawable, linear-gradients, gradientdrawable

I am creating GradientDrawable and it's working fine. But now I need to give centerX and centerY position of GradientDrawable and I am giving with below code

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.setColors(new int[]{StartColor, EndColor});
gradientDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(CenterXPosition, CenterYPosition); // CenterYPosition = 0.5 and CenterXPosition = (0-100) values I am giving
viewGradientLayout.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

but It is not working. setGradientCenter is not changing anything in my drawable.

this is my Imageview in which I am showing my drawable.

[image]

**Note:-**

1. I tried giving CenterXPosition values between 0.0 to 1
2. I tried giving

   ```
   gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
   ```

> gradient center stays at center position... without any movement.. What could be wrong? Thanks for your answers.
>
> any other solution to show like it also accepted.

Comment: I am have the exact problem, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @AndroidDev123 Sorry to say but the answer is No. And It is a google developer's issue and it is a registered issue already. link :- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36944181